# Do I have to build my WPF .NET 5 app with admin user? Access denied error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I'm constantly getting this error:

*"Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS2012  Cannot open '[myappdll].dll' for writing -- 'Access to the path '...\obj\Debug\net5.0-windows\ref[myappdll].dll' is denied.'   "*

when I try to build my .NET 5 WPF app. I'm using my VisualStudio under secondary user (on Win 10) for security purposes. If I build as administrator - it all goes well. If I switch to .NET Core 3 - also goes well. Apparently something is special about .NET 5.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you’re using a secondary user account then that user account probably doesn’t have Write permissions for the project directory. You don’t need admin rights for that. Check your NTFS ACLs.

Comment: @Dai. it can not be like that, because it works with .NET Core 3. Apparently, the user has sufficient permissions

Comment: Are your .NET Framework `obj or debug` directories are located in a path that is being denied by your company's anti-virus software. Like some of the words is the paths are blocked?

Comment: Which folder being used for output by .NET Core 3?

Comment: @Marshal it's my personal computer, so I didn't forbid access to any specific parts of path. All output directories are in /bin/ folder of my WPF app repository folder. So parent folder is apparently available for modification.